# LAN svn server visualsvn

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server, subversive

I am trying to create a svn repository over local area network.

I am using VisualSVN server software to do this.

I created a new repository and it automatically sets repository  as

```
http://mainframe/svn/ruby
```

I obviously chose the ruby folder name.

When I connect to this repository on the computer that is hosting the server, I get no problems.

But my problem comes when I try to check out the project into eclipse on my laptop.

It seems to connect properly to the repository. I can browse the repository in eclipse on my laptop.

But when I try to import project from SVN I get the error.

```
SVN: E175002: PROPFIND 'svn/ruby': See other (http://Mainframe).
```

Comment: Does the error really say "See other"? What's logged to VisualSVN Server's log (see http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/)? What's the version of Subversive / Subclipse?